# How can i have a good HTML report about my computer specifications?

Tags: system-settings

Is there a command to export my system specification to Html page , so i can open it a view all my system specification in a well recognized view .

Any Help ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by this command :

```
sudo lshw -html >myhardwarespec.html
```

this command will place a html file in the directory that i run this command , if you open it you can view all your computer specification .